# How to create a "I assume all risk using this app" Button upon initial launch?

Tags: ios

Many iOS apps have a button that shows up the very first time it's run that says 'I assume all risks....blah blah blah'.
I'd like to create one too but haven't been able to find out how to do this despite searching here and on the web in general.
Can someone please provide a pointer or example of how to accomplish this?
Thank you!
-Steve

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your app fires up and a certain bit of code in the app delegate gets fired. You can add code to this method. In addition, you have access to user defaults, use them to store simple data, such as a flag to indicate that the app has been run once.

I'm not going to give you code, but there's enough in that first paragraph that you should be able to implement this yourself using logic, and the "getting started" introductory materials i'm also not going to link here, since you should have read those yourself by now. If you haven't, please head on over to http://developer.apple.com/ios/ and get started.

Comment: Yep....was thinking I'd use the user default to store a flag as you suggested.....but I didn't know about the code running in the delegate upon app start up....I'll look in to that more and then create a Button of some sort. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a commet if you disagree with what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code snippet for doing this (I run it in the application didFinishLaunching method) :

```
-(BOOL)checkCGV {
    //We check if this is our first launch
NSString *fL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"risk_check"];
NSLog(@"cgv version is %@ should be %@", fL, [CGV CGVVersion]);
if (fL == nil || ![fL isEqualToString:[CGV CGVVersion]]) { // First launch or cgv not accepted or modified
    [self showCGV];
    NSLog(@"checkCGV returning NO");
    return NO;
}
NSLog(@"checkCGV returning YES");
return YES;
}
```

In my showCGV method :

```
-(void)showCGV {
    NSLog(@"showCGV");
    CGV *cgv = [[[CGV alloc] initWithNibName:@"CGV" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    [self.tabBarController  presentModalViewController:cgv animated:YES];
}
```

You can customize it according to your needs. Once the user clicked on the accept button, I simply set the userDefaults to the last version of the use contract. Like that if I change the contract, I'll just have to change the version in the CGV class and the user will be prompted again.